# SQL Server 2008 DBCC Problems

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, dbcc

We have a database Ms

```
DBCC CHECKDB (MS)
```

Or

```
ALTER DATABASE MS SET SINGLE_USER
DBCC CHECKDB(MS,REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS)
ALTER DATABASE MS SET MULTI_USER
```

Error message

> Msg 0, Level 11, State 0, Line 0: 
> A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.
>
> Msg 0, Level 20, State 0, Line 0: 
> A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.

---

After spending hours and testing each table, the problematic table was found "LC"

```
DBCC CHECKTABLE(LC)
```

Error Message

> Msg 211, Level 23, State 51, Line 1: 
> Possible schema corruption. Run DBCC CHECKCATALOG.

---

Now,

```
DBCC CHECKCATALOG
```

Message

> DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.

---

I also tried to have a look on indexes

```
SELECT * FROM sysindexes
```

Error Message

> Msg 211, Level 23, State 51, Line 1: 
> Possible schema corruption. Run DBCC CHECKCATALOG.
>
> Msg 0, Level 20, State 0, Line 0: 
> A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.

---

Again,

```
SELECT * FROM LC
```

Or

```
DROP TABLE LC
```

Error Message

> Msg 211, Level 23, State 51, Line 1: 
> Possible schema corruption. Run DBCC CHECKCATALOG.
>
> Msg 0, Level 20, State 0, Line 0: 
> A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.

---

I would not mind data loss for that particular table, I want to have the table dropped. Any ideas, please help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could `RESTORE` and never use [`REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS`](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/category/DBCC.aspx#p7) *(the article is worth reading)*! Seriously, no amount of DBCC voodoo will bring your database back to a pristine, working state.

Answer (score 2):

The most likely cause for these types of errors is a faulty disk drive.  Before you continue troubleshooting, test the hard disk with [hdtune](http://hdtune.com/) or `chkdsk /R`.  I'd also advise a memory test (there's a built in one called Windows Memory Diagnostic.)

Once you're sure the machine is OK, you could copy all good tables to a new database.  Then you can drop the old database.

Comment: The database is copied from the faulty system to a laptop.

The database is not shown on "Copy Database Wizard" or "Generate Scripts", therefore we would have to migrate data individually.

I would like to drop the table to save time, to give it a try. Any ideas?

Comment: @Nick Binnet: I don't think it's possible to repair that kind of damage (like GBN says, no amount of voodoo.)  The best I can think of is salvaging what you can to a new database.